# creating a Sparse matrix from a list of lists- R

Tags: r

I have a list called res which includes 83 lists with the following format. I need to generate one sparse matrix out of these lists. `Row` and `Columns` are indecies for the row and column of the sparse matrix and freq is the entry for that corresponding index.

Example of format for res[82] and res[83]:

```
[[82]]
   Row Columns Freq
2   82      33    1
3   82     173    1
4   82     211    1
5   82     247    2
6   82     480    2
7   82     541    1
8   82     974    1
9   82    1197    1
10  82    1416    1
11  82    1531    1
12  82    1797    7
13  82    2416    2
14  82    2530    1
15  82    2772    1
16  82    2970    2
17  82    3264    4
18  82    3416    1
19  82    3995    4
20  82    5593    1
21  82    6557    1
22  82    8141    1
23  82    9044    1
24  82   11889    1
25  82   12608    1
26  82   13352    1
27  82   13463    1
28  82   17937    1
29  82   29730    1
30  82   37712    1
31  82  258434    1

[[83]]
   Row Columns Freq
2   83     309    1
3   83     447    1
4   83     480    2
5   83     487    1
6   83     619    1
7   83     651    1
8   83     913    1
9   83    1555    1
10  83    1874    1
11  83    2416    1
12  83    3101    1
13  83    3856    1
14  83    3964    1
15  83    3995    1
16  83    4017    1
17  83    4362    1
18  83   10551    1
19  83   17130    1
20  83   29730    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sparseMatrix` from `Matrix` after `rbind`ing the `list` elements.

```
library(Matrix)
d1 <- do.call(rbind, lst)
res <- sparseMatrix(d1[,1], d1[,2], x = d1[,3])
```